# Why am I getting an Angular "Property success does not exist on type Promise"

Tags: angular, promise

I've dug around on Stack Overflow but I'm not able to find a solution since the answers are using older versions of Angular and don't work with the latest version.

When I try to call my registerUser with this snippet below it gives me the error "Property Success doesn't exist on type promise".

```
 //Register User
    this.authService.registerUser(user).subscribe(data=> {
      if(data.success){

      }
      else {

      }
    });
```

Here is where I've created my registerUser class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user,{headers: headers})
    .pipe(map((res:Response )=> res.json()));
  }
}
```

Comment: If you console.log(data);  before if/else what does it say? And the other hand data.hasOwnProperty('success') probably false.

Comment: As Beller mentioned, it seems your data object is a Promise. So calling success on it, returns an error since a Promise doesn’t have such a property

Comment: Just remove .pipe(map((res:Response )=> res.json())) completely..

Comment: I got an error for my .pipe(map((res:Response ) => res.json()))

ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a function

So I got rid of it completely as per MikeOne and the console.log I got in return was:

"Auth Service register" [object Object]. So I'm not sure what this means tbh and I'm not sure why getting rid of the .pipe(map) method got rid of the error? I'm still but a young chick trying to learn to fly on my own so any help would be great.